# Header and footer not showing

Tags: html, css

I am trying position 2 or more images on top of another, so I have been testing the following code

```css
#wrapper div{
 width: 100%;
}

#header div{
 width: 100%;
 clear: both;
}

#content div{
 position: relative; 
 overflow: scroll;
}

#image1
{
 width:100%;
 top: 0;
 z-index:2;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
}
#image2
{   margin-left:3px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 25%;
 top: 150px;
 z-index: 3;
}

#footer div{
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="header">
  <h3>Testing Header</h3>
 </div>
 <div id="content">
  <img id="image1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgg87.png" />
  <img id="image2" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Jpc.png" />            
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
  <h3>Testing Foorter</h3>
 </div>
</div>
```

However the header and footer wont show up, I am not sure if I must float something or clear it, I have been testing this on jfiddle and in my own server and nothing, the image tags fill the page, can anyone please show me how to solve this.

Comment: Why are you using absolute positioning?

Comment: I am trying to position 1 image over the other I understand that when you use absolute positioning on a div with relative positioning you achieve this, if you have a better result please I am open to suggestions, been at this all day now.

Comment: Ah, when you said one on top of another I thought you just meant stacked top to bottom, not in terms of z-index.

Comment: Is something like this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/176zc2cs/? I can't figure out how you want to use that very tall image.

Comment: Yes thanks that perfect, that is what I want - you are a star, how do I make that the answer to the question..... and the images arent what I am going to use, they just what came up in a sample code I found....

Comment: I'll post it as an answer in a second and you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your CSS rule:

```
#content div{
    position: relative; 
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

to:

```
#content {
    position: relative; 
    overflow: scroll;
    height:500px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/176zc2cs/)**

First, `#content div` isn't being applied to anything since it's looking to select divs within `#content` which don't exist. By removing the `div` part of that rule, you apply relative positioning to the content div which allows the absolutely positioned children to be positioned relative to the content container, not the entire page, as what was previously occurring.

Then you can specify a height of the content div as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can just refer to your header,content and footer as `#footer #header #content`. There is no need to specify the div tag after them in the css.

Edited JFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/50b7qxjs/1/

Comment: When I do that the images don't load at all.

Comment: More than “there is no need”, the issue is that `#header div` and `#header` mean two different things. The former is a div inside `#header`, the latter is `#header` itself.

Comment: thats my point now the images follow one after the other, not one on top of the other

Comment: Like this they ontop of each other, which is what I want, but the header and footer is on the wrong places - http://jsfiddle.net/L8pvxzrv/

Comment: Thanks, this was part of the answer, but what I ultimately was missing was the CSS height rule in the content div...

Answer (score 0):

This is because the z-index in your

```
#image1{
    width:100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index:2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yeffv8zu/)**

Change the z-index value with `z-index:-1`

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeffv8zu/3/)** for your requirement.

Comment: That helps, but I want them to be after each other, so now the heading and footer are right after each other at the top of the page.

Comment: I would like a header, that says like hellow welcome to "site name" then after that the content div that shows the 2 images on on top of the other, then at the bottom of the page the footer, thanks for the help.

Comment: don't forget to also keep in mind LiamWilson94's answer too. you shouldn't have `div` after `#footer #header #content` in the css because that's getting any div _descendants_ of `#footer #header #content`.